# image hosting for iPhone app

Tags: database, image

I currently am developing an iPhone app that displays many user-uploaded images. The images are stored on a Redhat Apache server ... but the loading speed is very slow. It's not an image server per se.

Any recommendations for a good image server (paid or unpaid) that's recommended for best speed of loading? I looked around Stack but could not find any that seem reliable.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using Amazon S3 (and cloudfront) as a CDN?

Comment: Yes, checking it out at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

1) What is your bandwidth and disk space requirement?
2) What is your budget for this?

If your site visitors are geographically spread-ed, for the Image / CSS & static content hosting, I would strongly recommend to use CDN hosting solutions. "CDN" offers the fastest content delivery for geographically located visitors.

CDN will be a bit costly, so, If you've visitors from any particular continent / region, it is advised to go for well known cloud hosting company in that region ...